# how to add if condition in react component TSX file in the rendor method

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, spfx

we are trying to get SP lists and list base template.
we can able to get Lists title along with list template but it returns template number.
so how can we query with **if condition** to display understandable string.
example

| List name | Base Template code | User-friendly name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Document | 101 | Document template |
| Customlist | 100 | custom list |

Expected output is

| List name | User-friendly name |
| --- | --- |
| Document | Document template |
| Customlist | custom list |

Here is the peace of code

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
    return (
    <div>
    <ol>
    {
    this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
    return(
    <li>
      <span>{mylists.Title}</span>
      <span>{mylists.BaseTemplate}</span>
      </li>);
      })
    }</ol></div>
```

Please find the output screenshot how its displaying with template number

[image]

Also we tried with

```
return(
    <li>
      <span>{mylists.Title}</span>
      
      if({mylists.BaseTemplate}= {'101'}) {
        <p>{"Document template"}</p>
        }
     </li>)
```

the above code is reading the entire string instead of condition
[image]

any assistance on how to apply condition and set/hardcode values for the specific template with some string value.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, try this

```
return (
  <li>
    <span>{mylists.Title}</span>
    {mylists.BaseTemplate === '101' && <p>Document template</p>}
  </li>
)
```

Comment: No above piece of code is not working and it through error at {mylists.baseTemplate with 
"this comparison appears to be unintentional " if 101 i want to set some string if 102 set another string etc.. i want to set using If ...else if